# Facebook Like Button disappears on clicking Like Button

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

Please note that the code below works fine and the FB Like button works when I click like on the button, but when I refresh thepage, the FB LIke button and other accompanying stats(no of likes, faces of ppl who like) disappears

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks !!!

```
<body>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.ge`enter code here`tElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=38135740xxxxxxx";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>

        <div class="selection">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/NA/jpg" height="100" width="180" />
            </div>
            <h3> <?php echo $favs[0]->name?>'s top five products</h3>
            <?php // print_r($favs[0]);?>
            <div class="selected">
                <div class="product"><img src=<?php echo '"../'.$favs[0]->photo1.'"'?> alt="Image not available" height="175" width ="175"/></div>
                <div class="product"><img src=<?php echo '"../'.$favs[1]->photo1.'"'?> alt="Image not available" height="175" width ="175"/></div>
                <div class="product"><img src=<?php echo '"../'.$favs[2]->photo1.'"'?> alt="Image not available" height="175" width ="175"/></div>
                <div class="product"><img src=<?php echo '"../'.$favs[3]->photo1.'"'?> alt="Image not available" height="175" width ="175"/></div>
            </div>
            <span style="float:left;padding-top: 10px;">Do You like the products above?</span>

            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <div class="fbLike">
                <fb:like send="false" width="400" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="textDesc">
            <h3>Participate in the Contest & Get to Know us More</h3>
            <p>You can also participate in the contest & get know us more by simply visiting us at</p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Hi Guys,
This problem occurred only on my localhost. On moving the code to my server, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are your site's pages protected with an .htaccess password?

If so, that could be the issue. I ran into this problem myself, and after going down the wrong path for a bit, I went back to my initial suspicion - htaccess password.

I didn't really look into the code, but I assume the button is set to have FB scrape the page after a user clicks like. With the password blocking things, FB can't scrape the page. Rather than displaying the button as if it hadn't been clicked, it just displays nothing - which is where my confusion came in.

After changing htaccess, you'll have to wait 24 hours for the page(s) to be scraped by FB when they're loaded. However, you can use the FB debugger (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to manually scrape individual pages.